# How to run BASIC on Windows XP Home?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, basic

I have Windows XP Home Edition.

Is it possible to run BASIC?

If yes, then how do I run all the commands in a text file in BASIC?

Comment: BASIC is a whole family of languages. Which dialect exactly are you using? Also, note that Visual Basic (that I notice you've tagged your question with) is significantly different from most other flavours of BASIC.

Comment: @Indrek I couldn't make a new tag, so I just decided to go with visual.

Comment: [Please don't](http://superuser.com/faq#signatures). Instead, focus on adding additional information to your question, as requested by @Vdt below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah you can run QBASIC in a cmd prompt. Download it. Then just open the file with the program in it and press F5 to run or choose Run from the menu. i've downloaded QBASIC 4.5 before, for windows xp.

I just tried 4.5 and it's fine, and there's a version 7.1 too
http://www.brisray.com/qbasic/qdload.htm